# Validator is called but error message is not displayed

Tags: jsf, message, validation

when i click on the command button. validate method is getting called but the error message is not getting displayed..

here is my code..

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:body>
        <p:panel style="width:500px">
            <h:outputLabel for="year" value="Select Year: *" style="font-weight:bold" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="year" value="#{leaveBean.year}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="null" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{leaveBean.yearDTO}" var="currentUser" itemValue="#{currentUser.name}" itemLabel="#{currentUser.name}" />
                <f:validator validatorId="LeaveCardValidator" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{leaveController.leaveCard}" update="updateList,updateDetails" id="button"/>
       <h:message for="year" style="color:red"/>
```

Comment: are you sure your input was not valid? if input is valid so there will be no message.

Comment: am sure my input is invalid .. and also my action is also getting called even though validation fails...

Comment: Don't forget the form, as a seperate naming container so if you name your message id msg and try to update it it will be form:msg

Comment: I tried with   <h:message for=form:year style="color:red"/>.. it didnt worked..

Answer (score 4):

You seem to expect that JSF auto-updates the `<h:message>` on every ajax request. This is untrue. Perhaps you're confusing with PrimeFaces `<p:messages>` or `<p:growl>` which have each an `autoUpdate` attribute which enables you to tell them to auto-update themselves on every ajax request.

You really need to make sure that the `<h:message>` is covered by the ajax update. Just give it an ID

```
<h:message id="yearMessage" ... />
```

and include it in the client ID collection of the ajax update

```
<p:commandButton ... update="updateList updateDetails yearMessage" />
```

An alternative would be to replace `<h:message>` by `<p:messages autoUpdate="true">`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where are the `updateList` and `updateDetails` are located but in the example give above you should use update="@form" instead or in addtion like this:

```
update="updateList updateDetails @form"
```

so that the form will be rendered again...

Comment: No its not, you need to make sure you render/update the `h:message` with you commandButton.

Comment: @erencan, try with plain `h:commandButton` with simple empty `f:ajax` , cause `p:commandButton` is boosted with default update of `@form` or something like this

Comment: @erencan, I don't what have you tried and based on what you are saying this thigs, but read this: http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#ValidationError , even when validation fails the RENDER_RESPONSE will be called.

Comment: Yes @Daniel you are right. update is necessary for `p:commandButton`.

Comment: rendering the form is not required for showing error messages as in the examples given by jsf..

Answer (score 0):

just use one of these :
update the whole form in order to update the content of
`<h:message />`

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{leaveController.leaveCard}" update="@form" id="button"/>
```

or give the `<h:message />` an id and id this id to the `<p:commandButton/>`
`<h:message id="msg" for="year" style="color:red"/>`

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{leaveController.leaveCard}" update="updateList,updateDetails,msg" id="button"/>
```

Comment: use firebug in firefox and get the correct clientId instead of year

Comment: clientId's are always random generated, if you give every element an id it will always be the same.