# JSF Validation Error message doesn't appear

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to validate a textfield.

I have a class `customer` with a field `name`:

```
@Size(min = 3, message = "At least 3 characters")
private String name;
```

This is the `index.xhtml`:

```
<p:outputLabel for="name" value="#{msg.name}" />
<p:inputText value="#{customer.name}" id="name" />
<h:message for="name"/>
<p:commandButton id="submit-button" value="#{msg.next}" action="next.xhtml"/>
```

When I enter a short string (with 2 letters), I get as a response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[4215878805973597748:-123199067583012360]]></update><extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension></changes></partial-response>
```

So, apparently, it recognizes, that the entered name is too short, but I don't get any error message in the view, as expected here: `<h:message for="name"/>`.

Comment: There is an attribute called `validatorMessage` for the `p:inputText`.  May be specifying this attribute shows the message defined in its value.

Comment: Can you tell what is the web server and the jsf versions you are working with?

Comment: @prasad: I use Glassfish 5 and JSF 2.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585042/validator-is-called-but-error-message-is-not-displayed is a better duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
<p:commandButton id="submit-button" value="#{msg.next}" action="next.xhtml"/>
```

The `p:commandButton` is a *Primefaces* library tag and is an enhanced version of the JSF's `h:commandButton`. The *Primefaces* button is by default ajax enabled.

In the example posted, when the commend button is pressed the form is processed (this is the default behavior) and the `next.xhtml` page is to be displayed.

The application is using *bean validation* to validate the input text; the `p:inputText` tag. When the user enters a 2 character value in the input text and presses the command button *the validation is happening*. The same page is shown but the expected validation message "At least 3 characters" is not rendered to the page.

One can see something like this in the server log (this is from Apache Tomcat's log files):

> org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute There are
>   some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a
>   chance to be rendered. These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
>   - Name: Minimum 2 characters are required!

This is because the request is originally to render the `next.xhtml`; this is the normal behavior. If one enters a valid name with 5 characters the next page will be displayed as expected. Due to the validation exception the current page is shown again but the message is not refreshed to the page. The message component needs to be refreshed explicitly.

Change this:

```
<h:message for="name"/>
```

To:

```
<h:message for="name" id="errmsg"/>
```

And, specify in the command button that this message component needs to be updated on submit.

Change this:

```
<p:commandButton id="submit-button" value="#{msg.next}" action="next.xhtml"/>
```

To:

```
<p:commandButton id="submit-button" value="#{msg.next}" action="next.xhtml" update="errmsg"/>
```

**Alternate:**

Another way of solving this is to simply submit a non-ajax request and then the full page will be refreshed by default - and one can see the validation message. In this case no need to have an "id" attribute for the `h:message` tag and the command button can be declared *without* the ajax behavior as:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" id="submit-button" value="#{msg.next}" action="next.xhtml"/>
```

**NOTES:**
The above conclusion is based on code tried on Apache Tomcat 8 web server, Apache MyFaces 2.2, Primefaces 5.3 and Hibernate Bean Validator 5.2.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Most is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I think the `p:commandButton` submit is an Ajax one, thus you have to specifically define components you want to be updated after the query is completed.

Since you are using primefaces, [here is a validation](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/validation.xhtml) example from their showcase.

Comment: As explained in this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585042/validator-is-called-but-error-message-is-not-displayed